# How can I tell what is actually terminating an http response?

Tags: networking, cache, browser-cache

#### I've got a web server that's serving up some static files. At times when the server is under heavy load, it sends out partial responses with a 200 HTTP status.

#### This is a problem for my app. Why?

- I have cache headers set on the response that are intended to keep the file around for a long time, since these files are static and should never change.
- Every once in a while some end users's are getting only part of a javascript file, with an HTTP status of 200.
- This file gets cached by the browser, and breaks my app!

I've tried 2 different web servers (Jetty and Apache) and see the issue happening with both, with or without a load balancer in front of them (haproxy). This makes me think it's not the webserver itself, though maybe this is expected behavior for any web server under heavy load?

#### How can I find out what's causing this issue, or protect against it?

EDIT: These requests also have a `Content-Length` response header being provided as well.

Comment: How big is the js file?  Is it always truncated at the same size?  Are you able to get a pcap from the client when it happens?

Comment: They're bigger, around 4 mb uncompressed.... different sizes when they're cut off too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a packet capture of the problem happening. It could be that all your stuff is working fine, but the end users have buggy browsers or are behind buggy web proxies, firewalls, or NAT gateways that are truncating the file.

You might want to look at how your servers / reverse proxies / load balancers are handling the Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding headers when serving that JS file. Also review the rules for these things in [RFC 7230 section 3.3.2, "Content-Length"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) and some of the following sections.